# how to get Model List<string> in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this Model  and return its when form Edit :

```
public class NewsVM
{
    public List<string> Tags{get;set;}
}
```

and in Action:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
     //create instance and fill it
     return View(mymodel);
}
```

and in jQuery in View I want Get `Tags` and Add All of them to my div . How can I do this ?

I use this but not work
:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Tags.Count; i++) {
            alert('@Model.Tags["i"]');
        }

     </script>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use razor to add them?

Comment: can You your answer ? I want Get All List<stting> and Add All of them to the div .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the model to a javascript array

```
var tags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tags));
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    alert(tags[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (Model != null)
{
         for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++) 
         {
             <script type="text/javascript">
                  alert('@Model.Tags[i]');
             </script>
         }
}
```